# Add a dependency to an existing shared object library

Tags: c++, linker, ld

Say that I have three libraries: libMissingSymbol.so, libMiddle.so, and libSymbolHaver.so. libMissingSymbol contains a symbol defined in libSymbolHaver, but only has a dependency on libMiddle. libMiddle is supposed to have a dependency on libSymbolHaver, but it doesn't. I don't have the source code or unlinked object files that these libraries were assembled from. Is it possible for me to link libMiddle with libSymbolHaver so that libMissingSymbol can find the symbol it needs at load time? Is there any way that I can fix this using only these three shared object files and any necessary tools? I have to end up with libraries with the same contents (including SONAMEs) barring the dependency change to libMiddle in order to not break things further down the line in my project.

Hypothetical readelf output (trimmed for relevance) to clarify:

```
$ readelf -s libMissingSymbol.so
123: 00000000     0 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND MangledSymbol

$ readelf -d libMissingSymbol.so
Dynamic section at offset 0x42434 contains 37 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libMiddle.so]
 0x0000000e (SONAME)                     Library soname: [libMissingSymbol.so]

$ readelf -d libMiddle.so 
Dynamic section at offset 0x75b28 contains 29 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000e (SONAME)                     Library soname: [libMiddle.so]

$ readelf -s libSymbolHaver.so
     35: 00064d0c     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   22 MangledSymbol
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible for me to link libMiddle with libSymbolHaver so that libMissingSymbol can find the symbol it needs at load time?

No: all UNIX linkers, except the AIX one, consider `.so` the *final* link product and no further modification is possible.

**Update:**

> viability of doing this a different way (e.g. decompiling libMiddle and rebuilding it with the correct dependencies)?

I don't believe that is viable either -- it is *really hard* to modify a fully-linked ELF file and not violate myriad of internal consistency constraints.

I suggest the following approach, which is very likely to just work(TM).

1. Abandon your "only using these three libraries" restriction. It appears to be artificial and unnecessary.
2. Copy `libMiddle.so` -> `libZiddle.so` (be sure to make a copy of the original `libMiddle.so` somewhere else in case things go wrong).
3. binary-patch the `SONAME` in `libZiddle.so` to match the new name. The string `"libMiddle.so"` is in the `.dynstr` section of the library, and (I believe) is not hashed in any way, so changing one letter in it will not introduce any self-inconsistencies into the new library.

   Once you've done this, compare `readelf -a libMiddle.so` and `readelf -a libZiddle.so`, the `SONAME` should be the *only* difference.
4. Remove `libMiddle.so`.
5. Link a new `libMiddle.so` containing `some_unused_function()`, *and* having dynamic dependency on *both* `libZiddle.so` *and* `libSymbolHaver.so`.

Now any binary that currently links against `libMiddle.so` and fails with missing symbol (e.g. `libMissingSymbol.so`) will find the new (empty) `libMiddle.so`, but because the new `libMiddle.so` requires both `libZiddle.so` (where most of the symbols are) *and* `libSymbolHaver.so`, it should just work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have any insight about the viability of doing this a different way (e.g. decompiling libMiddle and rebuilding it with the correct dependencies)?

Comment: Re: point #1, I had the constraint because the point of all this is to emulate a different execution environment that I don't have control over (I have a more detailed post on a more specific forum [here](https://www.chiefdelphi.com/forums/showthread.php?t=153697) if you care to know the details). Your revision led me to examine my situation again, though, and I discovered the real problem: version skew in my libraries. I didn't have to try your approach, but I'm accepting your answer; thanks again for the help.